# Doctrine entity to CSV

Tags: symfony, csv, doctrine

Since few hours i try to convert doctrine2 entities to csv.

My idea was to convert doctrine entities to array with (in my repository ):

```
return $query->getArrayResult();
```

And after, convert this array to csv.

But the convertion array to csv don't work because there are  DateTime Object in my field....

Does anybody have a simple way to convert doctrine entities to CSV ?

(ps : I tried to search by myself on many post without success, so sorry to disturb you :-(  )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent getting errors while converting to Datetime you will have to do it manually. Iterate across all objects and format the datetime using the following for the DateTime objects:

```
 $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

For example you could do the following:

```
$csv = "";
foreach ($result as $item)
{
   foreach($item as $element)
   {
      if($element instanceof DateTime)
        $csv .= $element->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //Converts the Datetime to string for the given format
     else
        $csv .= $element;
     $csv .= ",";
    }
    $csv .= "\r\n"; //Adds new line
}
echo $csv;
```